# Can you block someone on Instagram if their account has been deactivated?

Tags: instagram

This is kind of petty but I cannot understand how a deactivated Instagram account can be blocked.

A friend claimed to have blocked me after deactivating my account. He assumed I blocked him.

My understanding is that if your Instagram account is deactivated, people are unable to view your profile. As such, they unable to block you... Is this right?

So I was either removed before deactivation or shortly after reactivating?

Answer (score 1):

You can block a person who deactivated their Instagram, if you have exchanged private messages with them. Just go to that person private message in the inbox , then go to settings, and the press block sender. I promise that person will be blocked, even if they reactivate their account.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is absolutely right. No one can block or follow/unfollow a deactivated account.

To block someone, one has to go to that person's profile. But if that person's profile is deactivated, then no one can go to that person's profile and cannot block.

So yes, you were either removed before deactivation or shortly after reactivating.

Learn more about [How do I block or unblock someone?](https://help.instagram.com/454180787965921)

Comment: Thank you for affirming my thoughts 

Answer (score -1):

Deactivated account can't be blocked, because such account is inactive/inaccessible.

> To block or unblock someone:
>
> > **1.** Tap their username to go to their profile
> >
> > **2.** Tap [image] (iPhone/iPad) or [image: enter image >description here] (Android) in the top right
> >
> > **3.** Tap **Block** or **Unblock**
>
> **[https://help.instagram.com/](https://help.instagram.com/454180787965921)**